# How can I use commercial at sign in Objective-C macro?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

How can I use commercial at sign in Objective-C macro?

I know it is not recommended, but seems it is possible somehow? Since `libextobjc` provides `@weakify`, `@strongify`, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libextobjc` uses preprocessor trickery to make you think it's an `@command`.

```
#define weakify(...) \
    try {} @finally {} \
    metamacro_foreach_cxt(ext_weakify_,, __weak, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Note the missing `@` on the `try`. 
So `@weakify` expands into `@try {} @finally {} [injected code]`.

You could use the same trick, but I suggest you stick with plain macros.

Comment: Oh, I see. I already saw this piece of code, but didn't notice try block. Thanks! :)