# Meaning of Objective-C macros prefixed with an at (@) symbol

Tags: objective-c, macros, reactive-cocoa

The ReactiveCocoa framework makes use of `weakify` and `strongify` macros, both of which are preceded by an '@' symbol.

Here's an example (From this [file](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/fd533d07b64d40cf79d069584d8cd95158998095/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/NSControl+RACTextSignalSupport.m#L19)).

```
- (RACSignal *)rac_textSignal {
        @weakify(self);
        return [[[[RACSignal
                ... 
               ];
}
```

What is the significance of the at symbol that is a prefix to the macro name? (NOTE: I have checked the macro, and it is called 'weakify', not '@weakify', so it isn't just the macro name!).

The macro itself is defined here:

https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTScope.h#L45

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a dup of that question. Weakify is not a language keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use commercial at sign in Objective-C macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599174/how-can-i-use-commercial-at-sign-in-objective-c-macro)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no special meaning to macros starting with an `@`. This is done in libextobjc to make the `@weakify` and `@strongify` macros seem more idiomatic with the rest of the language.

Technically, the `@` is not part of the macro. The macro is just `weakify` or `strongify`. The actual body of the macro, though, is written such that it will not compile unless preceded with an `@`. This is done by adding an empty `@autoreleasepool {}` at the beginning of the macro, but stripping off the leading `@`.

Comment: Thanks! Although personally I think this is confusing. Why make these macros look any more 'special' than others?

Comment: just came here to say that's maybe the most clever use of autoreleasepool i've seen in a long time

Answer (score 7):

The `@` isn't part of the macro. `weakify` is defined as:

```
#define weakify(...) \
    autoreleasepool {} \
    metamacro_foreach_cxt(ext_weakify_,, __weak, __VA_ARGS__)
```

So `@weakify(self)` becomes:

```
@autorelease {} metamacro_foreach_cxt(ext_weakify_,, __weak, self)
```

Comment: Thanks! but why not include the @ in the macro?

Comment: My only guess is that the macro author was trying to be slick making the macro to appear to require the `@` before the macro name.

Comment: Slick? Maybe, confusing ... definitely! Why try to make it look like a language feature when it isn't? Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: My use of the term "slick" wasn't a compliment. :) I agree it's a bad idea.

Comment: @ColinE They perform a task that's really more at the language level (manipulating variable declarations) than your typical macro or function invocation, and the @ adds visual weight. It was also meant to draw parallels with `@synchronized`, etc., although obviously the usage is a bit different in practice.

Comment: @maddy don't know if using trick like that (`@autoreleasepool, @try @catch, ...`) to make the use of @ can have any performance impact? I remember nicklockwood advised not to use `@try @catch` in Objc

Comment: @entropy Of course it has an impact. It's adding needless code just to get the `@` in the macro name. Whether the impact is meaningful is another question. It all depends on how it's used.